# How to correctly send an image to the backend (nodejs) using multer in React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, react-native, multer

I'm having trouble sending a photo, in a **PUT** route, be it with Axios or Fetch, anyway, my Nodejs backend is configured and the whole upload process works normal testing by Insonmia, but in React Native It does not work properly.

**BACKEND - CONTROLLER FOR UPDATING USER DATA**

```js
  async updateUserData(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { username, status } = req.body as IBodyData;

    try {
      const userExists = await knex('tb_user')
        .where('id', Number(id))
        .first();

      if (!userExists) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'User does not exist.' });
      }
      
      const serializedUserInfo = {
        photo: `${process.env.BASE_URL}/uploads/${req.file.filename}`,
        username,
        status,
      };

      const updateInfo = await knex('tb_user')
        .update(serializedUserInfo)
        .where('id', Number(id));

      if (!updateInfo) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Error updating data.' });
      }

      return res.json(updateInfo);
    } catch(err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error on updating user.' });
    }
  }
```

**BACKEND - ROUTE**

```js
routes.put(
  '/updateuser/:id',
  multer(multerConfig).single('userphoto'),
  UserController.updateUserData
);
```

**CONFIG MULTER**

```js
export default {
  fileFilter: (req: Request, file, cb) => {
    const allowedMimes = [
      'image/jpeg',
      'image/jpg',
      'image/pjpeg',
      'image/png',
    ];

    if (!allowedMimes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
      return cb(new Error('Invalid file type.'));
    }

    return cb(null, true);
  },
  limits: {
    fileSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024,
  },
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'uploads'),
    filename: (req: Request, file, cb) => {
      const filename = `${randomBytes(6).toString('hex')}-${file.originalname}`;

      return cb(null, filename);
    }
  })
} as Options;
```

**REACT NATIVE - FUNCTION FOR GET DATA OF PHOTO AND SET ON STATE**

```js
  function handleUploadImage(image: IImagePickerResponse) {
    if (image.error) {
      return;
    }

    if (image.didCancel) {
      return;
    }

    if (!image.uri) {
      return;
    }

    setSelectedImage({
      fileName: image.fileName,
      fileSize: image.fileSize,
      type: image.type,
      uri: image.uri,
    });
  }
```

**REACT NATIVE - FUNCTION FOR SEND DATA IN API**

```js
  async function handleSaveChange() {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();

      formData.append('userphoto', {
        uri:
          Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? selectedImage?.uri
            : selectedImage?.uri?.replace('file://', ''),
        type: selectedImage.type,
        name: selectedImage.fileName,
      });
      formData.append('username', usernameInput);
      formData.append('status', statusInput);

      console.log(formData);

      await api.put(`/updateuser/${userData?.id}`, formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      });

      // const updateUser = await fetch('http://192.168.2.8:3333/updateuser/1', {
      //   method: 'POST',
      //   headers: {
      //     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      //   },
      //   body: formData,
      // })
      //   .then((response) => {
      //     response.json();
      //   })
      //   .then((response) => {
      //     console.log(response);
      //   })
      //   .catch((err) => console.log(err));


      return Toast.success('Informações alteradas com sucesso.');
    } catch (err) {
      const {error} = err.response.data;

      return Toast.error(error);
    }
  }
```

obs: A note to take into account is that in the `formData.append ('userphoto', value)` part if the value has sent a normal json object, the request is neither made nor the `Network Error` error even IP address being correct the port too, anyway, and if I use `formData.append ('userphoto', JSON.stringfy(value))` the request is made normally but in the backend the photo arrives as `undefined` and the rest of fields are sent and received normal.

I really tried several things and I couldn't, I changed the type of the PUT method to POST without success, add `'Accept': 'application/json'` without success, as I said, the normal sending by Insomnia is working.

Finally, here is the lib configuration I used to get the photo:

**REACT NATIVE IMAGE PICKER**

```js
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(
  {
    title: 'Selecione uma imagem',
    takePhotoButtonTitle: 'Tirar foto',
    chooseFromLibraryButtonTitle: 'Escolher da galeria',
    cancelButtonTitle: 'Cancelar',
    noData: true,
    // storageOptions: {
    //   skipBackup: true,
    //   path: 'images',
    //   cameraRoll: true,
    //   waitUntilSaved: true,
    // },
  },
  handleUploadImage,
)
```

**SOLVED**

Apparently it was a problem with the version of React Native, I am currently using version 0.62.XX

To resolve, just comment line number 43 in the file:

> android/app/src/debug/java/com/mobile/ReactNativeFlipper.java

The code is this:

> builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor (networkFlipperPlugin));

Comment: Can you verify that `selectedImage?.uri` exists before uploading maybe by adding a `console.log`?

Comment: @eol I just modified the code here for the changes you suggested to me, and as I said earlier if I send `formData.append('userphoto', {...})` it returns the following error: [TypeError: Network request failed ]

And about "selectedImage?.uri" it has the correct URI.

Comment: Weird - there's on open issue on github (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28551), maybe your problem is related to that. Other than that I'm out of suggestions unfortunately :/

Comment: OMG, it seems to be a problem with the version of React Native even though I'm using ^ 0.62.13, I think I will upgrade to 0.63

Comment: Thanks a lot for the attention you saw, I spent almost 2 days trying to find the error and when I saw the error was not mine, the solution was to comment:

`line 43 // builder.addNetworkInterceptor (ew FlipperOkhttpInterceptor (networkFlipperPlugin));`

In: `android/app/src/debug/java/com/mobile/ ReactNativeFlipper.java`

I am Brazilian and I asked on StackOverflow in Portuguese and the staff ignored, I thank you for your attention, and sorry for my English hahaha.

Comment: De nada, happy to help! :) Maybe you can post the fix as your own answer, in case others have the same problem.